# Combine a list of first names with a list of last names to create full names

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have 2 lists: one with first names and another with last names.

list one has 200 elements and each of those elements can have up to 5 first names.

list two has exactly the same amount of last names as first names in the same spots on the list.

I'd like to merge the two lists and create full names.

list1 looks like this:

```
-Index   -Type    -Size    -Value
- 0      -list    -4       -['Robert', 'Bruce', 'George', 'Gavin']
- 1      -list    -2       -['Aaron', 'Fred']
```

list2 looks like this:

```
-Index    -Type    -Size    -Value
- 0       -list    -4       -['Leslie', 'Scott', 'Smith', 'King']
- 1       -list    -2       -['Weston', 'Cranswick']
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
-Index    -Type    -Size   -Value
- 0       -list    -4      -['Robert Leslie', 'Bruce Scott', George Smith',.....']
- 1       -list    -2      -['Aaron Weston', 'Fred Cranswick']
```

I tried simply adding the list together:

`Full_Name = First_Name + Last_Name`

but unfortunately it isn't that simple

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through one of the matrixes concatenating with the other matrix concatenating with the same indexes, something like:

```
for i, list in enumerate(first_name_lists):
  for j, first_name in enumerate(list):
    first_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name_lists[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you should be able to iterate the lists using an index and join like this?

```
first_names_1 = ['Robert', 'Bruce', 'George', 'Gavin']
first_names_2 = ['Aaron', 'Fred']

last_names_1 = ['Leslie', 'Scott', 'Smith', 'King']
last_names_2 = ['Weston', 'Cranswick']

def join_arrays(first_names, last_names):

    full_names = []

    if len(last_names) == len(first_names):
       for index in range(0,len(first_names)):
            full_names.append("{} {}".format(first_names[index], last_names[index]))


    return full_names

full_names = join_arrays(first_names_1, last_names_1) + join_arrays(first_names_2, last_names_2)

print("{}".format(full_names))
```

Comment: Although this isn't a very "pythonic" answer, i thought being a bit more verbose might help.

Comment: Thanks you for that. The output I get is ['Robert', 'Bruce', 'George', 'Gavin']['Leslie', 'Scott', 'Smith', 'King']

Comment: If you're looking for the output the new edit shows, just remove this line "full_names = join_arrays(first_names_1, last_names_1) + join_arrays(first_names_2, last_names_2)" where it concatenates the two outputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[' '.join(name for name in names) for names in zip(pair[0],pair[1])] for pair in zip(list1, list2)]
```

This line will join nested elements of two lists separated by space.

**Sample Code**:

```
list1 = [['Robert', 'Bruce', 'George', 'Gavin'], ['Aaron', 'Fred'], ["Alif"]]
list2 = [['Leslie', 'Scott', 'Smith', 'King'], ['Weston', 'Cranswick'], ["King"]]

fullnames = [[' '.join(name for name in names) for names in zip(pair[0],pair[1])] for pair in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Output:

```
fullnames = [['Robert Leslie', 'Bruce Scott', 'George Smith', 'Gavin King'],
     ['Aaron Weston', 'Fred Cranswick'],
     ['Alif King']]
```